# Git publish on Jenkins build

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have an aggregator project built in jenkins and I want to publish a file that contains the version control of my project:

```
app.version=1.1
```

Every build, the value is incremented so the file is modificated, I need commit and push the file to git repository.

I add a "Post-build Actions" with "Branches" config: http://postimg.org/image/mtz6czv0l/

The build (git clone and generate war) works fine, but this post action dont add and push the file to git.

If I check workspace files, has a change after build:

```
  $ git status
HEAD detached at a0cde37
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   application.properties

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

The log is showing up all right:

```
Done creating WAR target/radar-varejo-1.1.war
 > git tag -l jenkins-radar-varejo-32 # timeout=10
 > git tag -a -f -m Jenkins Build #32 jenkins-radar-varejo-32-SUCCESS # timeout=10
Pushing HEAD to branch develop at repo origin
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git config --local credential.helper store --file=/tmp/git8741248240629941444.credentials # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true push http://192.168.10.107:8083/morro-das-pedras/radar-varejo.git HEAD:develop -f
 > git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
```

How I can do it? Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Just  do `git add application.properties &&
git ci -m 'Updating application.properties && git push origin branch` as a last build step? :)

Comment: I tried this, but the post build dont save git envs, such username and pass: `fatal: could not read Username for 'http://192.168.10.107:8083': No such device or address`

Comment: it has if you are have git plugin installed

Comment: i have, the git clone that create war works fine, and there I configured user and pass. Why the same configs didn't use here?